# how to refresh the json data on tap or on pressed in the same page flutter

Tags: json, flutter

I am trying to refresh the page on tap or on pressed the icon .Example In  cart screen i was added the products, and i want to delete one product when click on delete button and also at the same time refresh the page data.i am getting the data from rest api.

Comment: please put the code of your implementation

Comment: Have you tried StatefulWidget?

Comment: we need more infos about your code to help you. In general you need a StatefulWidget and onRefresh you have to call the api once again, update your variable inside a setState() call and redraw your Widgets (if its not just a Textfield that displays the informations)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [ValueNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier-class.html) and [ValueListenableBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html). They are usefull to update some widget (subtree) when some value is changed.

Example:

```
// somewhere in State class
final cartNotifier = ValueNotifier<List<Product>>(null);

final products = <Product>[];

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  cartNotifier.value = products; // Initialize cart somehow
}

// somewhere in `build` function wrap the `cart` grid
ValueListenableBuilder<List<Product>>(
  valueListenable: cartNotifier;
  builder: (BuildContext context, List<Product> products, _) {
    return ListView.builder(
    ); // This ListView shows list of `Product` items
  }
);

// somewhere in `build` function when product is removed
IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
  onPressed: () {
    products.removeWhere((product) => product.id == <deletedId>);
    cartNotifier.value = products;
  }
);
```

As result as `cartNotifier's` value will be changed ValueListenableBuilder re-build its subtree (i.e. ListView with products)